# About Hedging of One-touch Options

Tags: options, black-scholes, stochastic-calculus, hedging, exotics

The pricing of American Digital Call (one-touch Calls) has the following formulas, taken from P13, [the textbook](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/howison/barriers.pdf)

\begin{aligned}
C_{\mathrm{d}}^{\mathrm{Am}}(S, t ; E) & =\left(\frac{S}{E}\right)^{\lambda_{+}}-\left(\frac{S}{E}\right)^{\lambda_{+}} N\left(-d_{+}\right)+\left(\frac{S}{E}\right)^{\lambda_{-}} N\left(d_{-}\right) \\
& =\left(\frac{S}{E}\right)^{\lambda_{+}} N\left(d_{+}\right)+\left(\frac{S}{E}\right)^{\lambda_{-}} N\left(d_{-}\right) .
\end{aligned}

Where

\begin{aligned}
\lambda_{ \pm} & =\frac{1}{2}\left(1-k^{\prime}\right) \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left(k^{\prime}-1\right)^2+k} \\
& =\alpha \pm \sqrt{-\beta},
\end{aligned}

and

\begin{equation}
d_{\pm}=\frac{\log (S / E) \pm \sigma^2 \sqrt{-\beta}(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}}
\end{equation}

Which are solved from

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial C_{\mathrm{d}}^{\mathrm{Am}}}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2 \frac{\partial^2 C_{\mathrm{d}}^{\mathrm{Am}}}{\partial S^2}+(r-D) S \frac{\partial C_{\mathrm{d}}^{\mathrm{Am}}}{\partial S}-r C_{\mathrm{d}}^{\mathrm{Am}}=0
\end{equation}

Now I am curious about, from a market maker's perspective, how does he hedge this when selling a one-touch call to clients. Assume the underlying has a liquid vanilla product markets(european options/futures). And the tenor and strike of that one-touch call matches the existing vanilla product markets.